# ST_MakeLine is changing the y-coordinate of some points

Tags: postgis

I was attempting to make a polygon out of a set of points when I ran into this problem. I'm gathering the points into an array and passing to to ST_MakeLine. When I query the same point index after using MakeLine, the point value has been rounded.

```
if NOT(ST_Equals(pointArray[0], ST_StartPoint(ST_MakeLine(pointArray)))) then
   raise notice 'Point Array: %, Line: %', ST_AsEWKT(pointArray[0]), ST_AsEWKT(ST_MakeLine(pointArray));
end if;
```

Output:

```
NOTICE:  Point Array: SRID=4326;POINT(55.5 46), Line: SRID=4326; LINESTRING(55.5 45.5,55.5 46,56 46,56 45.5,55.5 45.5)
NOTICE:  Point Array: SRID=4326;POINT(53.5 50), Line: SRID=4326;LINESTRING(53.5 49.5,53.5 50,54 50,54 49.5,53.5 49.5)
NOTICE:  Point Array: SRID=4326;POINT(48.5 46), Line: SRID=4326;LINESTRING(48.5 45.5,48.5 46,49 46,49 45.5,48.5 45.5)
```

Is this a bug?

VERSIONS:

PostgreSQL 9.5.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4090" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.0.2, released

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was just some confusing on how the indexing works.

I changed to the -1 index on the point array and stopped getting the error.

```
if NOT(ST_Equals(pointArray[-1], ST_StartPoint(ST_MakeLine(pointArray)))) then
   raise notice 'Point Array: %, Line: %', ST_AsEWKT(pointArray[-1]), ST_AsEWKT(ST_MakeLine(pointArray));
end if;
```

Does anyone know why the last point in the point array becomes the start point of the line? This doesn't seem very intuitive.

EDIT: MakeLine works perfectly, the error was on my end. The indexing on my point arrays started at -1, which is what was causing the confusion.